# Add class to nav when scrolling to the anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is dynamic. The nav changes based upon the page.  The code here adds a class to the nav as you scroll to the section and then removes it as you scroll past. The problem is it only removes as you scroll down not up past the section. How do I do my condition to remove classes as you scroll up while achieving adding the class and removing it as you scroll down??

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    var sectionelements = jQuery('.nav li');
    (function(jQuery) {

    var scrolling = function(){
        jQuery(sectionelements).each(function(){
            var object=jQuery('#'+this);
            var wh = jQuery(window).height();
            var st = jQuery(document).scrollTop();
            var ot = jQuery(object).offset().top;
            var eh = jQuery(object).height();                   
            var href="a[href*=#"+object.attr('id')+"]";
            if(st>ot){
                jQuery(href).addClass('posreached');
            }
            if (st>ot+eh) {
                jQuery(href).removeClass('posreached');
            };
        })
    };
        jQuery(window).scroll(scrolling);
        jQuery(window).bind('resize orientationchange',scrolling);

//fire initial scroll
jQuery(window).scroll();
    })(jQuery);
});
```

Comment: Can you profide a fiddle example?

Comment: Check out the waypoints library http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/

Comment: trying to create it in fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this:

```
if(st>ot){
    jQuery(href).addClass('posreached');
}
if (st>ot+eh) {
    jQuery(href).removeClass('posreached');
};
```

even in the second state the first will be true, so u need to add:

```
if(st>ot || st<ot+eh){
    jQuery(href).addClass('posreached');
}
```

give it a try

Comment: to what add class or remove class

Answer (score 0):

I used these for my conditions and it worked

```
                    if(st>ot){
                        jQuery(href).addClass('posreached');
                    }
                    if (st<ot) {
                        jQuery(href).removeClass('posreached');
                    }
                    if (st>ot+eh) {
                        jQuery(href).removeClass('posreached');
                    }
```